# Nexus 5x Crashed and can not enter Recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, nexus-5

My nexus 5x Crashed and then constantly starting up to the "Google" splash screen. I wanted to execute the “Recovery mode” but unfortunately without the success.

I executed the following:

```
1. Press & hold Volume Down and Volume Up, and then press & hold Power simultaneously until the device turns on. I see the word Start with an arrow drawn around it.
2. Press Volume Down twice to designate Recovery mode.
3. Press Power to restart into Recovery mode
```

Unfortunately I see the "Google" splash screen each time I do it.

What can I do to recover my phone?
Can I access the data (photos) on the phone?
What does `DEVICE STATE  - locked` status on the start screen mean?

Answer (score 1):

1. Unfortunately it's not a very common problem, so I assume neither Google not LG really bother fixing it (I have the same issue). The 7.1.1 upgrade caused some sort of hardware bug that couldn't be fixed.

   The solution is to contact the seller of the phone. If you bought it from Google and it's still under warranty, you're in luck because you can get a full refund. Otherwise, just explain the situation to them and see what they can do.
2. Concerning your photos, well, your hope is that you had backups... You can try freezing your phone (literally). In my case it gave me about 5 minutes of uptime (it shuts down once gets warm), so if it's the case for you, you might have enough time to pull your photos and all the other info from it.
3. `DEVICE STATE - locked` means that you didn't unlock the bootloader. That, in turn, doesn't permit you to perform various operations with fastboot or adb. To unlock the bootloader you need to access the Developer Options in the settings when the device is powered up.

So I hope I shed some light on your issue. Hope you can have something done with it.

UPD: I called the Google Play support and after going through the problem they agreed to send me a new 5X. The entire solution took about 20 minutes. So I strongly encourage you to do it :)